# Best way to handle between in two dates in postgresql on timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am having date field in my table in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`  wanted to get records between `11-july-2020` inclusive `14-july-2020` but records are missing on `14th`. Tries `>= && <`  `SYMMETRIC`  but non of them is working.

currently using `select .... from employee where ... and created_on in between ?1 and ?2` . It is excluding record created on 14th.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
where col >= '2020-07-11' and col < '2020-7-15'
```

Or, to express this using timestamps:

```
where col::timestamp >= '2020-07-11'::timestamp and
      col::timestamp < '2020-07-14'::timestamp + interval '1 day'
```

Note that the higher end is one day later than 2020-07-14, so you can get all times on that day.

You can also use `between` as:

```
where col::date between '2020-07-11'::date and '2020-07-14'::date
```

But I discourage the use of `between` with date/time data types -- precisely because of the problem that you are having with the time component.

Comment: but for `interval '1 day'` it will lead to data discrepancy because in between date`7th july to 12th july` it will shows up record upto 13th july

Comment: @RaushanSetthi . . . I don't understand your comment.  The dates in the question concern July 14th and including the entire day.  All the versions in this answer do that.  Nothing in the answer only gets values "up to July 13th".

Answer (score 0):

If your field has format `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` it is a timestamp field not a date field. That makes a big difference in the comparison that needs to be done as @Gordon shows. If you compare a timestamp to a date(14-july-2020) the date will be turned into a timestamp with a time of 00:00:00:

```
select '07/14/2020'::timestamp;
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2020-07-14 00:00:00
```

That means you will miss the timestamps on the 14th that fall after Midnight of 13/14th.